# Treating UIView as button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have put a UIView in my navigation item and I am using the JSBadgeView on it. I want for a different screen to appear upon clicking it, but I'm not sure how. iOS won't let me make a seque and I checked off "button" under traits but I'm not sure what to do after that. In Android, I would just do Object.setOnClickListener but as far as I know there is no method like that iOS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add a tap gesture recognizer to it.

Comment: i didn't understand nothing...you also use incorrect terminology to call objects and other..

Comment: I'm not sure what incorrect terminology I used. JSBadgeView is a custom badge, you can find on github.

Comment: why not just use a UIButton and add the badge view to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a tap gesture recogniser:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandler:)];
```

Add the tap gesture to the UIView:

```
[aView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then implement the tap handler:

```
- (IBAction)tapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { // Handler code }
```

You should just be able to manually perform the required segue in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to implement the touchesBegan method as follows

This will detect when the view was clicked

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```